# bash difference between 2 dates in bash by yyyy-mm-dd in N days

Tags: linux, bash, variables, awk, sh

I write a long script in bash and somehow I am able to print 2 dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.

My outputs are like 2019-12-30 and 2019-12-21

1st date is always yesterday date, my output won't print date function it just prints a value of date, 
So. I need to tell bash that its a date and give me a difference in days.

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date --date=yesterday +%F)
END=$(date --date "2 days ago" +%F)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))

echo " $DIFF "
```

It shows me 85 only. how can I get the difference in dayes like "1" (2 days ago -  yesterday)

I would appreciate if someone answer with some explanation

PS: i dont know if datediff is premade. the function of Linux, it's not in my centos 6

Comment: see the accepted answer for [Quickly calculate date differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24636/234539)

Comment: @markp i saw that in 1st resul of google, but it didnt work for me. Let me edit my question

Comment: that `datediff()` function works for me (see my answer); if it still doesn't work for you then please update your question with more details, eg, the values stored in `${START}` and `${END}` and the (wrong) output you're generating; it may also help if you provide your `date` version (`date --version`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

*see the accepted answer for* [Quickly calculate date differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24636/234539)

The person who answered that question wrote a custom function called `datediff`:

```
$ datediff() {
    d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
    d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
    echo $(( (d1 - d2) / 86400 )) days
}
```

We can use this same function to compare the 2 dates from the question:

```
$ START=$(date --date=yesterday +%F)
$ END=$(date --date "2 days ago" +%F)
$ echo "${START} : ${END}"
2019-12-30 : 2019-12-29
$ datediff "${START}" "${END}"
1 days
```